# converting 'cacert.crt' file to pks 12

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssh, ssl, certificate

This is the third or so in a chain of questions to implement ssl certificates. To date the public and private keys are created in the server and are operational, however the browsers do not recognize the server as legitimate. The objective is to create a pks12 file to import. The question is "how to create a pks 12 file that can be loaded into firefox and chrome to support https operations. Below is an example from the web on how to do this; this may not be the best way.

openssl pkcs12 -export -in pem-cert-file -inkey pem-key-file -out pkcs12-cert-and-key-file

1. I assume pem-cert-file is cert file created, it is labeled server.pem and begins with the line -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
2. What is the pem-key-file?
3. If it is the private key file is it safe to use it in this way? Does sending the pkcs12 format file off site compromise the private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a sequence to a p12 format file and then a p12 format file to a pem file. The pem file is then copied to imap.pem.

> $ openssl pkcs12 -export -in hostname.crt -inkey hsotname.key -out
>   hostname.p12 $ openssl pkcs12 -in hostname.p12 -nodes -out
>   hostname.pem